# "Complex" JQuery selector with :not()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select all my < li >s that do not contain 'Month' as text. This is my selector and current is a variable containing the string 'Month'.

```
$('section ul li:not(section ul li:contains("' + current + '"))')
```

It is the :contains() selector that do not work in the :not() selector as when I remove the contains() section, I get the good selection of elements (nothing). Also it is not my variable current that is incorrect, I have tested it.

Maybe we can not put : types of selectors in : selectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$('section ul li:not(:contains("' + current + '"))')
```

Comment: Wow, I wanted to try that, but I never did it haha. Thank you it works!

Answer (score 2):

Use a filter instead of Sizzle:

```
$('li').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf('Month') === -1;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/seancannon/h2twZ/

Comment: Is it faster using a filter?

Comment: Less code, often its easier to read. Cases like this most likely will be noticeable only on like legacy IE or a slow tablet, but it's good to know when you can be lax and when you need to save CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$('section ul li:not(:contains("' + current + '"))')
```

Comment: You mean the same answer that was given 8 minutes before yours?

Comment: Ok no need to be funny about it - I was using my phone and the screen doesn't refresh the same as it does on a PC. Surely you must realise this is just a cross-post? It's not like I replied a day later is it?